# Using gsub to extract character string before white space in R

Tags: r

I have a list of birthdays that look something like this:

```
dob <- c("9/9/43 12:00 AM/PM", "9/17/88 12:00 AM/PM", "11/21/48 12:00 AM/PM")
```

I want to just grab the calendar date from this variable (ie drop everything after the first occurrence of white-space).

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
dob.abridged <- substring(dob,1,8)
dob
[1] "9/9/43 1" "9/17/88 " "11/21/48"
dob.abridged <- gsub(" $","", dob.abridged, perl=T)
> dob.abridged
[1] "9/9/43 1" "9/17/88"  "11/21/48"
```

So my code works for calendar dates of length 6 or 7, but not length 8. Any pointers on a more effective regex to use with gsub that can handle calendar dates of length 6, 7 or 8?

Thank you.

Answer (score 139):

No need for [substring](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/substr.html), just use [gsub](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/grep.html):

```
gsub( " .*$", "", dob )
# [1] "9/9/43"   "9/17/88"  "11/21/48"
```

A space (), then any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`) until the end of the string (`$`). See [?regex](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/regex.html) to learn regular expressions.

Comment: The only advice I can share  here is that a `sub` is enough since there is only one string end position.

Answer (score 17):

I often use `strsplit` for these sorts of problems but liked how simple Romain's answer was.  I thought it would be interesting to compare Romain's solution to a `strsplit` answer:

Here's a `strsplit` solution:

```
sapply(strsplit(dob, "\\s+"), "[", 1)
```

Using the microbenchmark package and `dob <- rep(dob, 1000)` with the original data:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                    expr       min        lq    median
                   gsub(" .*$", "", dob)  4.228843  4.247969  4.258232
 sapply(strsplit(dob, "\\\\s+"), "[", 1) 14.438241 14.558832 14.634638
        uq       max neval
  4.268029  5.081608  1000
 14.756628 53.344984  1000
```

The clear winner on a Win 7 machine is the `gsub` regex from Romain.  Thanks for the answer and explanation Romain.

Answer (score 17):

The library `stringr` contains a function tailored to this problem.

```
library(stringr)
word(dob,1)
# [1] "9/9/43"   "9/17/88"  "11/21/48"
```

Comment: Changing the second argument to -1 extracts the text after the final space, which is what I wanted. i.e. ```word(dob,-1)```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to extract characters from alphabet before a white space is:

You have to install the package: "stringr"

```
stringr::str_extract(c("juan carlos", "miguel angel"), stringr::regex(pattern = "[a-z]+(?=\\s)", ignore_case = F))
```

`[a-z]`: matches every character between a and z (in Unicode code point order).

`+`: 1 or more.

`(?=\\s)`: Lookahead, followed by \s (which is white space) (not matching \s).

More info: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score -1):

Another regex pattern to extract the date only

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(dob, regex("\\d{1,}\\/\\d{1,}\\/\\d{1,}"))
#[1] "9/9/43"   "9/17/88"  "11/21/48"
```

- `\\d{1,}`: Matches digits at least 1 time
- `\\/`: Escapes forward slash