# regex from first character to the end of the string

Tags: regex, r

In a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895050/using-gsub-to-extract-character-string-before-white-space-in-r) someone asked how to grab from beginning of string to first occurrence of a character.  I'd like to extend my own knowledge of regex by asking how to grab from a certain character of the string to the end.

***How could I use regex (not `strsplit`) with gsub to grab from the beginning of the first space to the end of the string?***

```
dob <- c("9/9/43 12:00 AM/PM", "9/17/88 12:00 AM/PM", "11/21/48 12:00 AM/PM")
```

Here I tried: `gsub(".*? ", "", dob)`  but it grabs from the last space not the first so I tried `gsub(".{1}? ", "", dob)` but it is overly greedy because of the period.

Final solution would be the same as:

```
sapply(lapply(strsplit(dob, "\\s+"), "[", 2:3), paste, collapse=" ")
##[1] "12:00 AM/PM" "12:00 AM/PM" "12:00 AM/PM"
```

**NOTE: R regex is not identical to regex in general**

Comment: Your result suggests you want everything from the first character to the second space.

Comment: what a doof I am.  Fixed that Matthew.

Comment: what you're asking for and the final result you show are still inconsistent. Hence you get two answers that give you two different things.

Comment: I went back and made everything consistent. My apologies.  I was thinking something and typed that rather than the real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
gsub("^(.*?) .*$", "\\1", dob)
# [1] "9/9/43"   "9/17/88"  "11/21/48"
```

If you want from the first space to the end of the string, try :

```
gsub("^.*? (.*)$", "\\1", dob)
# [1] "12:00 AM/PM" "12:00 AM/PM" "12:00 AM/PM"
```

Comment: Both Daniel and Juba's answer worked for me but this one is more generalizable in that `gsub("^.* .*? (.*)$", "\\1", dob)` can grab from the second space on.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the indicator for the beginning of the string:

```
gsub("^.*? ", "", dob)
```

Note the caret at the beginning. Your first solution wasn't too greedy, but found two strings and replaced them.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

> dob
>       [1] "9/9/43 12:00 AM/PM"   "9/17/88 12:00 AM/PM"
>       [3] "11/21/48 12:00 AM/PM"
>   gsub("(.*?) (.*$)", "\2", dob)
>       [1] "12:00 AM/PM" "12:00 AM/PM" "12:00 AM/PM"