# Vectorizing A Custom Function

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I wrote this function to return the string before a certain character, which goes like so:

```
strBefore <- function(find, x, last = FALSE, occurence) {

  # Checking.
  if (class(x)[1] != "character") { stop("The strBefore function only supports objects of character class.") }

  # Getting the place of the find, and handling both caes of last.
  fullPlace <- gregexpr(find, x)[[1]] # Gets the location of the occurences of find in x.

  # Handling the case where last is TRUE.
  if (last == TRUE) { place <- max(fullPlace) # Grabbing the latest character index if last is TRUE.
  } else { place <- min(fullPlace) } # Otherwise, getting the first space.

  # Handles the occurrenceargument if given.
  if (!missing(occurrence)) { place <- fullPlace[occurrence] }

  # Subsetting the string.
  xlen <- nchar(x) # Getting the total number of characters in the string.
  x <- substr(x, 1, place - 1) # Minus 1 because we don't want to include the first hit for find.
  return(x)

}
```

Where `find` is the character you want the string before, `x` is the character, `last` asks if you to get before the last occurrence of `find`, and `occurrence` designates which occurrence of `find` to get before (overrides `last` if given).

If I use it on a single character object, it works fine like so:

```
> test <- "Hello World"
> test2 <- strBefore(" ", test)
> test2
[1] "Hello"
```

However, if I use it on a character vector, it cuts each item in the vector at the same place as the first item:

```
> test <- c("Hello World", "Hi There", "Why Hello")
> test2 <- strBefore(" ", test)
> test2
[1] "Hello" "Hi Th" "Why H"
```

Now, this link here does provide me with a method for doing what I want:

[Using gsub to extract character string before white space in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895050/using-gsub-to-extract-character-string-before-white-space-in-r)

However, I do like having the functionality of the "occurrence" argument, which returns the string before the 2nd, 3rd, etc... occurrence of the find argument.

Just as a note, I can vectorize my function with `sapply` like so:

```
> test <- c("Hello World", "Hi There", "Why Hello")
> test2 <- sapply(test, function(x) strBefore(" ", x))
> test2
Hello World    Hi There   Why Hello 
    "Hello"        "Hi"       "Why"
```

Which somewhat solves my problem...but is there a way to do this more cleanly without having to use an `apply` function? **I'm not looking for a solution to what `strBefore` does, but more a solution to how to vectorize custom functions. Thanks for your time.**

Comment: You can vectorize the function like this `Vectorize(strBefore, "x")(" ", test)`.

Comment: Walk through your function with example input that doesn't do what you want and figure out where it breaks.

Comment: `char <- ' '; gsub(paste0(char, '.*'), '', test)` ?

Comment: You might want to look at `regmatches()`, which - in tandem with a regular expression - might give you what you want without having to write as much of a custom function.

Comment: @lukeA Thanks for you reply, I think you're the only one that followed I was looking more for a way to vectorize my function instead of how to do what it does. Do you know if there's a way to make my function automatically vectorize without having to wrap it? Or is that what sapply and Vectorize are for? I could just make a wrapper function that would satisfy this.

Comment: `Vectorize(strBefore, "x")` returns a function, which vectorizes the argument `x`. So you could do sth like `vStrBefore <- Vectorize(strBefore, "x")` and just use `vStrBefore(...)`. Or you vectorize it beforehand by iterating over the `x`s and aggregating the results; e.g. by using `sapply` or a `for` loop.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like my best bet. Thank you. :)