# How to retain specific parts of an element in a column and eliminate everything else in R?

Tags: r

I have a column containing the brand and model of cars. How to keep only the brand and remove the model? In the original dataset, the brand and the mode were separated by a space. So I tried this:

```
carprice$CarName=gsub(pattern = " *", replacement = "",carprice$CarName)
```

What happened was the space got eliminated and now the brand and the model names are concatenated. I am not able to even undo it.

Comment: Essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895050/using-gsub-to-extract-character-string-before-white-space-in-r

Comment: `gsub("(.*)\\s.*", "\\1", carprice$CarName)`

Comment: Your attempt might work if you used `" .*"` as the pattern. At the moment you're matching zero or more spaces only. Adding `.` means you match a space followed by zero or more of any character.

Comment: @Marius Now I don't think " .*" will work because there is no space in the names anymore. As I said the Brand Name and the Model Name are concatenated. I now need only the brand name or a way to undo the change so that I can use the gsub command with " .*"

Comment: @zacdav Thank you. May I know What your code does? Cause it did not work for me.

Comment: Start again then.... My code removes the space and everything after

Comment: @zacdav I have come very far. I don't think start over. Any other way where I can just extract the brand names? For example the elements are like this:

[1] "alfa-romerogiulia"           "alfa-romerostelvio"          "alfa-romeroQuadrifoglio"    
  [4] "audi100ls"                   "audi100ls"                   "audifox". I just need alfa-romero, audi